# Xcode 13.3 new error message with @MainActor

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-concurrency

I updated today to Xcode 13.3 and now my code can't compile anymore.

I get two error messages. It seems there is a connection between the errors.

1. First error:

   > Property 'startAnimation' isolated to global actor 'MainActor' can not be mutated from a non-isolated context

   in this line

   ```swift
   kuzorra.delay(interval: 1.5) {startAnimation.toggle()
   ```
2. Second error:

   > Mutation of this property is only permitted within the actor

   in this line

   ```swift
   @State private var startAnimation = false
   ```

I don't really understand how to fix these errors. Any help or hints are welcome :-)

For better understanding my view:

```swift
struct AnimationView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var kuzorra: Kuzorra
    @AppStorage ("isSoundEnabled") var isSoundEnabled: Bool = true
    @State private var startAnimation = false
    var label: Bool
    var correctAnswer: String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(label ? "RICHTIG!" : "FALSCH!")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .padding(.top)
            
            
            if !label{ Text("Richtige Antwort: \(correctAnswer)")
                    .font(.caption)
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .minimumScaleFactor(0.01)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
            }
            VStack(alignment: .trailing){
                
                Text(" - Weiter - ")
                    .padding(.bottom, 5)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.caption2)
            }
        }
        .bgStyle()
        .rectangleStyle()
        .padding()
        .opacity( startAnimation ? 1 : 0)
        .rotationEffect(.degrees(startAnimation ? 2880 : 0))
        .scaleEffect(startAnimation ? 2 : 1/32)
        .animation(Animation.easeOut.speed(1/4), value: startAnimation)
        .onTapGesture {
            kuzorra.currentPage = .page3
        }
        .onAppear {
            if isSoundEnabled   {   AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(1320))
            }
            kuzorra.delay(interval: 1.5) {startAnimation.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the code for `delay`:

```swift
@MainActor
class Kuzorra: ObservableObject {

.
.
.

func delay(interval: TimeInterval, closure: @escaping () -> Void) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + interval, execute: closure)
    }
```

There I get the following error message:

> Passing non-sendable parameter 'closure' to function expecting a @Sendable closure
> Parameter 'closure' is implicitly non-sendable.

After pressing <kbd>fix</kbd> button this error message disappears..

Comment: It depends on the context of the code. A `@State` property is usually inside a SwiftUI `View` which does run on the main actor.

Comment: I've attached my code. It is a normal SwiftUI View. So I think it should be in the main actor?!

Comment: I was on the wrong path, not the @State property causes the problem, it is the delay function. this is in embedded in a class witch runs as a main actor...

Comment: Watch [this video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10133/), it explains your issue.

Comment: Thanks, I will look this video. For the moment I solved my problem by moving the delay() from the class to the view. at least a workaround...

Comment: You need to understand that your code was always wrong, but Apple is only now starting to enforce the real rules. Keep in mind that concurrency is a work in progress!

Comment: Sure, in know that I have to dive deeper :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably prudent to avoid using GCD’s `asyncAfter` within Swift concurrency codebase. So, rather than:

```swift
.onAppear {
    if isSoundEnabled {
        AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(1320))
    }
    kuzorra.delay(interval: 1.5) {
        startAnimation.toggle()
    }
}
```

Consider using the [`.task`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/task(priority:_:)) view modifier (which takes an `async` closure, and is also cancelable) and [`sleep(for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/sleep(for:)/) (which, unlike traditional `sleep` API, does *not* block the thread):

```swift
.task {
    if isSoundEnabled {
        AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(1320))
    }
    try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1.5))
    if !Task.isCancelled {
        startAnimation.toggle()
    }
}
```

That achieves `asyncAfter` like behavior within Swift concurrency. Needless to say, you could also use `do`-`try`-`catch` pattern:

```swift
.task {
    if isSoundEnabled {
        AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(1320))
    }
    do {
        try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1.5))
        startAnimation.toggle()
    } catch {
        // print(error)
    }
}
```

If you use `Task.sleep` pattern, you either have to `try?` and then check `isCancelled` or `try` and `catch` the error.

But the main point is to avoid `asyncAfter` in Swift concurrency.